# Grammar of 見えぬ in 星とたんぽぽ by Misuzu

Tags: negation

I'm reading a poem by Misuzu, 星とたんぽぽ。

I don't understand the grammar of this line:

昼のお星は眼にみえぬ。

This is my understanding:

1. 昼のお星は　the subject: stars during the daytime
2. 眼に　to the eye (why not 目?)
3. みえぬ　I assume is a form of 見る - 見える (to be able to see) Is the ぬ form a 'childish' negative? Or an abbreviation of 〜ない？

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/235  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18548  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9581

Comment: ～ぬ following the _-a_ stem for regular verbs, or the _-e_ stem for verbs like 見える, is a negative.  This is an ancient and Classical Japanese form of modern ～ない, and is also one of the conjugations of negative ～ず.  See the links that Eddie Kal posted, those should answer your question about the word みえぬ.